# c++: Need correct syntax to avoid MISRA 14-6-1 warning. Class template with dependent base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, constructor, misra

I've written a lexer/parser for a language called SML. It is used in electronic meters. I am in the phase of static code analysis. Lint is reporting a MISRA violation 14-6-1. The rule (required) is: "In a class template with a dependent base, any name that may be found in that dependent base shall be referred to using a qualified-id or this->"

System: Raspberry PI 3B, g++: cc version 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10), PC LINT  v9.0k. Language: C++98

Code excerpt:

```
class SmlElementBase
{
    public:
        SmlElementBase(void) {}
        virtual ~SmlElementBase(void) {}                    
        // Main "parse" pure function to be implemented / overwritten by     all derived classes
        virtual prCode parse(ParserContext &pc) = 0;        
        // Per default an SML Element is not a container
        virtual boolean isContainer(void) const { return false; }
};

template<const Token::TokenType tokenType, const TokenLength TokenLength=0UL>
class SmlPrimitive : public SmlElementBase
{
    public:
        SmlPrimitive(void) : SmlElementBase() {}
        virtual ~SmlPrimitive(void) {}
        virtual prCode parse(ParserContext &pc);    // Parse function     (calls match function)

    protected:      
        virtual boolean match(const Token *token);  // Match token with     expected type and length
};

template<typename ValueType, const Token::TokenType tokenType, const TokenLength tokenLength=0UL>
class SmlPrimitiveWithValue : public SmlPrimitive<tokenType, tokenLength>
{
    public:
        //lint -e{1960,915,919}
        SmlPrimitiveWithValue(void) : SmlPrimitive<tokenType, tokenLength>(), value() {}; 
        // SmlPrimitiveWithValue(void) : SmlPrimitive<tokenType, tokenLength>(), value::SmlPrimitive() {};     NO DIFFERENCE
        virtual ~SmlPrimitiveWithValue(void) {}
        // Parse function is inherited. 
        //lint -e{1925}
        ValueType value;    // Value will be stored here. Public because of visitor pattern
    protected:
        virtual ::boolean match(const ::Token *token); // Match token with expected type and length and store value
};

typedef SmlPrimitiveWithValue<u8, Token::UNSIGNED_INTEGER, 1UL>             Unsigned8;
```

Lint reports the following:

```
SmlPrimitiveWithValue(void) : SmlPrimitive<tokenType, tokenLength>(), value() {};
```

Note 1942: Unqualified name 'SmlPrimitive' subject to misinterpretation owing to dependent base class [MISRA C++ Rule 14-6-1]

for the constructor of SmlPrimitiveWithValue.

What is the correct syntax to avoid the MISRA rule violation?

I googeld and tried and tried, but could'nt come up with a solution.

EDIT:

I tried also:

```
SmlPrimitiveWithValue(void) : ::SmlPrimitive<tokenType, tokenLength>::SmlPrimitive(), value() {};
```

This does not compile. Compiler message:

```
/home/pidata/project/ehz/include/parser.hpp: In constructor ‘ParserInternal::SmlPrimitiveWithValue<ValueType, tokenType, tokenLength>::SmlPrimitiveWithValue()’:
/home/pidata/project/ehz/include/parser.hpp:281:50: error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
      SmlPrimitiveWithValue(void) : ::SmlPrimitive<tokenType, tokenLength>::SmlPrimitive(), value() {};
                                                  ^
/home/pidata/project/ehz/include/parser.hpp:281:50: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token
```

Comment: You forgot `()`?

Comment: Does this compile? Does `value::SmlPrimitive()` compile? Better to try compiling it first, before running the MISRA checker.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the () in the post. Just corrected it. Everything compiles. Code runs. No error, no warning (-wall -pedantic)

Comment: This seems like a bit of a false positive, since the technically correct interpretation really is that the name `SmlPrimitive` is found in the global namespace, not as the injected class name from the base class (though that would have the same meaning if it were found). Maybe `::SmlPrimitive` would shut it up?

Comment: MISRA C++ seems to data back to 2008. Are you sure that all the rules are still relevant ?

Comment: @Christophe MISRA guidelines are still relevant in various industry sectors.

Comment: I tried several ideas already. ::SmlPrimitive . . .  does not compile. I guess the problem is the initializer list part of the constructor. In other parts of the class definitions/declarations qualified names or the usage of the this pointer work. But not in the constructor.

Comment: What happens if you remove `SmlPrimitive<tokenType, tokenLength>::SmlPrimitive()` altogether? Or is this against some other MISRA rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit silly, since unqualified names (not used in a class member access) are [not looked up in dependent bases at all](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep#3).  There’s therefore no possibility of (say) ill-formed NDR from the interpretation in a specialization differing from that in the definition.

Anyway, what the guideline wants is for you to write

```
SmlPrimitiveWithValue(void) : ::SmlPrimitive<tokenType, tokenLength>(), value() {};
```

(with whatever namespace contains `SmlPrimitive`, if any).  That is, to name the base class with a *qualified-id*.

Comment: Hm. This does not compile. It says, I must give the template class name as qualifier. I tried all possible combinations now. But my guess is (this I need to check) that the Base Class is not instantiated and the compiler does not know it. I will check in the evening.

Comment: @Armin: The syntax [certainly works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RLj5V168OeIUj0EZ).  Feel free to edit the exact new code and error into the question if necessary.

Comment: Doess still not compile. Gcc version above. Complete project, including makefile, can be downloaded from www.montigny.info/ehz20180903.zip   File is: parser.hpp   Project status: 1st draft

Comment: Meanwhile I found out that the MISRA message is triggered by the typedef. Maybe thats the first time, when the template is instantiated. But I do not know . . .

Comment: @Armin: Instead of `::SmlPrimitive<tokenType, tokenLength>::SmlPrimitive()` (which tries to initialize a constructor...?), you want `ParserInternal::SmlPrimitive<tokenType, tokenLength>()` (which uses the relevant namespace name).

Comment: Still no success. This compiles, but I get from LINT: File p:\project\ehz\include\parser.hpp, Line 281 SmlPrimitiveWithValue(void) : ParserInternal::SmlPrimitive<tokenType, tokenLength>::SmlPrimitive(), value() {};    Note 1942: Unqualified name 'ParserInternal' subject to misinterpretation owing to dependent base class [MISRA C++ Rule 14-6-1] .    And this message I get 12 times. For each Instantiation of the class.

Comment: YEAH! Success. I found it. This works:  SmlPrimitiveWithValue(void) : ::ParserInternal::SmlPrimitive<tokenType, tokenLength>::SmlPrimitive(), value() {}; But I do not know why . . .      But thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The initial `::` is a unary scope resolution operator that unambiguously names the global namespace (to avoid hitting the same MISRA rule for the name `ParserInternal`).  That **last** `::SmlPrimitive` is finding the injected-class-name; it surely should work without that.